# How to run .apk on Saucelabs using Android emulator?

Tags: java, android, facebook, appium, saucelabs

I want to run facebook.apk at saucelabs. I successfully downloaded apk file to sauce server using curl acording to SauceLabs [instructions](https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/rest-api/#upload-file).

I used this code to launch application:

```
capabilities.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.4.0");
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Selendroid");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","4.2");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("app","sauce-storage:facebook.apk");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.facebook.katana.FacebookLoginActivity");  
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.facebook.katana");
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "300000");
try {
    BaseAppiumTest.driver = new RemoteWebDriver
            (new URL("http://SL_name_private:SL_key_private@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabilities);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I constantly used to get this error:

> POST /session
>   0 (+0.28s)
>   desiredCapabilities: {"deviceName":"Android Emulator","automationName":"Selendroid","proxy":{"proxyAutoconfigUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19876/pac.js","proxyType":"PAC"},"newCommandTimeout":"300000","platformVersion":"4.2","platformName":"Android"}
>   => A new session could not be created. (Original error: hasInternetPermissionFromManifest failed. Error: Command failed: ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found )

I have checked fb.apk locally and, seems, it was downloaded correctly, as well.

Comment: Did u get any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, code above should work. The issue was, I failed to deploy apk via curl correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide (automationName, appActivity, appPackage) capabilities while executing tests in Saucelabs emulators.

You can use the sample capabilities below:

```
caps.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.13.0");
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung Galaxy S9 WQHD GoogleAPI 
      Emulator");
caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
caps.setCapability("browserName", "");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.0");
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("app", "sauce-storage:WhatsApp.apk");
```